# Checkbox of inner div not being checked JQuery Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Consider this code sample below:

This works

```
<div class="row">
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3" />
    </div>
</div>
```

But when I add the class it does not work

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="checkbox i-checks">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery code below

```
$('#checkbox3').prop('checked', true);
```

I am trying to check a checkbox of an inner div using JQuery. The checkbox is in  an inner div( many layers of nesting) and is a different bootstrap class from the parents. I am trying to check the check box of inner div, however unable to check it. How do I set the checkbox of inner div of a different class.

I am using the below to import the styles

```
@Scripts.Render("~/plugins/iCheck")


$('.i-checks').iCheck({
    checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-green',
    radioClass: 'iradio_square-green',
});
```

Styles:

```
@section Styles {
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/plugins/iCheck/iCheckStyles")
}
```

Comment: can you give a fiddle ?

Comment: BS probably expects the `checkbox` class to be on the checkbox itself, it doesn't look inside for a checkbox.

Comment: looks fine in codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/YvawZM

Comment: @NagaSaiA I dont think that has rendered the bootstrap. The checkbox looks like an ordinary checkbox

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution, but I will post it here in case someone needs it in future.

I added the below to the JQuery

> .icheck('update')

```
$('#checkbox3').prop('checked', true).iCheck('update');
```

Adding the below for reference

http://icheck.fronteed.com/

Answer (score 0):

It actually does work when you add class

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#checkbox3').prop('checked', true
   );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
    <div class="checkbox i-checks">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3" />
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Doesnt work. The above code does not render bootstrap